# Como ordenar a data em php

Tags: php, html, mysqli

Boa tarde, eu preciso ordenar as datas que vem do banco de dados, pelo dia/mês/ano.
EX: 16/07/2020
30/07/2020
01/08/2020

```
$sql_listar = "SELECT idprova as idprova, descricao as descricao ,disciplina as disciplina, DATE_FORMAT(dtprova,'%d/%m/%Y') as dtprova, idprof as idprof from prova order by dtprova";
```

Comment: faltou informar como a data está no banco. DATETIME? DATE?

Comment: O que voc devê fazer se alguém responder sua pergunta? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers  Veja como aceitar em https://i.stack.imgur.com/evLUR.png

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo Estou usando o DATE

Answer (score 0):

Assim amigo:

```
echo date('d-m-Y', strtotime($sql_listar));
```

Estudo **date()** para saber de outros parâmetros. E **strtotime()** também.

Answer (score 0):

Troque o `alias` da coluna dtprova, por exemplo, `ALIASdtprova`.

```
SELECT idprova as idprova, descricao as descricao, disciplina as disciplina, idprof as idprof, DATE_FORMAT(dtprova,'%d/%m/%Y') as ALIASdtprova from prova ORDER BY dtprova DESC;
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para retornar com a data, (mudei o campo `data` para o tipo `DATE`)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não funcionou, removeu a data

Comment: @FernandoMoreira, como assim removeu a data? Você incluiu ela no select para ser mostrada? dtprova as dtprova ?

Comment: Funcionou no SQL, mas no PHP não funcionou removeu a data